# splitting strings in R with backslash

Tags: r, strsplit

I am trying to parse out a file address and want to extract both the file location and the file name.  For example, I want this:

```
"C:\Users\carriebrown\Desktop\test\Project_8754.csv"
```

to become this:

```
"C:\Users\carriebrown\Desktop\test\" and "Project_8754.csv"
```

I am attempting to use:

```
strsplit(file,'\\', fixed=TRUE)
```

But continue to the get the error:

> Error in strsplit(file, "\", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument

Is there a way to do this in R with strsplit? If not, is there a way to do it in a different manner?

Comment: See `?basename`.  The functions listed there will do this task for you.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Benjamin !

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
path <- unlist(strsplit('C:\\Users\\carriebrown\\Desktop\\test\\Project_8754.csv','\\',
                        fixed=TRUE))
file <- path[length(path)]
path <- paste(path[-length(path)], collapse='\\')
path
#[1] "C:\\Users\\carriebrown\\Desktop\\test"
file
#[1] "Project_8754.cs
```